# Where did i wrong?Take 2 integers, pass function and calcualte sum of cubes

Tags: python

The code is:Take 2 numbers from the user. Pass these two numbers to a function `mathExp()`. This function will calculate the sum of the cubes of the two numbers.
Return and print this value.
Function Structure:

```
int mathExp(int,int)
```

My code is:

```
num1 = int(input("write a number: "))
num2 = int(input("write a number: "))

def mathExp(num1,num2):
    print(num**3 + num**2, mathExp(num1,num2))
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot wrong with this code:
First, you are calling the mathExp function IN itself. Thats recursion and I dont think that you want to do this.
Second, the parameters of the mathExp function are called `num1` and `num2`. But in the function you use just `num` which doesnt exist.

So what you probably want to do is this:

```
num1 = int(input("write a number: "))
num2 = int(input("write a number: "))

def mathExp(n1,n2):
    return n1**3 + n2**3

print(mathExp(num1, num2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your mathExp function was wrong. Try this instead:

```
num1 = int(input("write a number: "))
num2 = int(input("write a number: "))

def mathExp(num1,num2):
    ans = num1**3 + num2**3
    return ans

cubes = mathExp(num1, num2)
print(cubes)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
# take two number as input from the user
num1 = int(input("write a number: "))
num2 = int(input("write a number: "))

# define the function which calculate the sum of cubes of the input numbers
def mathExp(num1,num2):
    result = num1**3 + num2**3
    return result

# call the function with user input and print the result
print(mathExp(num1, num2))
```

Example:

```
write a number: 4
write a number: 7
407
```